# Cropperjs: Move and resize cropped area

Tags: javascript, cropperjs

What is a proper way to "restore" a crop box rectangle (or square) when cropperjs ready for use?

I have a global variable `details` which stores every position changes. Then I can use it to restore the previous position (size, offset, scale and etc). I know the way how to get that data (from `crop()` method), but I don't understand how to set it and move, scale crop box to the previous position (crop box — I mean the area over the image that you can resize, stretch when defining the region for cropping)

```
// gloval variable
let details;

// ...

cropper = new Cropper(document.querySelector("#image"), {
    viewMode: 3,
    zoomable: false,
    aspectRatio: 1,
    ready() {
        if (details) {
            // ... restore previous crop box position
        }
    },
    crop(event) {
        console.log(event.detail.x);
        console.log(event.detail.y);
        console.log(event.detail.width);
        console.log(event.detail.height);
        console.log(event.detail.rotate);
        console.log(event.detail.scaleX);
        console.log(event.detail.scaleY);

        details = event.detail;
    },
});

// ...
```

Can you advice me the proper way for it. I am using v1.5.12

Comment: Oh found it : in options, pass `ready(){this.cropper.setData(initData)}, ` with `initData` an object such as `{x:20, y: 40, width: 400, height: 280}`